# spyOn function that returns an express Response, throws error Argument of type 'Response<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'

Tags: typescript, express, jasmine

I am trying to mock a function that returns an express response.

This is the function i am trying to mock:

```
export async function getTokenExample() {
  return await superagent
    .post(`/gettokenexample`)
    .type("form")
    .send({
      foo: "cia",
    });
}
```

This is the spy:

```
spyOn(tokenExample, "getTokenExample").and.resolveTo({body: {token: "mocked_token"});
```

However the above throws an error:

```
  Type 'Response<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': accepted, badRequest, body, clientError, and 25 more.
```

I've tried a cast on Response to that object but now luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `getTokenExample` returns `Promise<Response>`, that means spy needs to resolve to `Response`. From there, you have to cast your resolving `Promise` to `Response`

```
import {Response} from 'superagent';

it('should pass', async () => {
    spyOn(tokenExample, "getTokenExample").and.resolveTo({body: {token: "mocked_token"}} as Response);

    ...
});
```

Comment: I needed also to add as unknown before as Response.
That, good sir, saved my day. Thank you very much